# HttpClient Replicate in Java from C#

Tags: java, c#, android, json, xamarin

I have an Android project built in Xamarin (.NET) I wish to convert to native Java. In the Xamarin app I have built an API class used to access HTTP data utilising Generics, which looks like this:

```
public class InventoryAPI {
HttpClientHandler handler;
Uri baseAddress;
HttpClient client;

public InventoryAPI() {
  // .. Init code here
}

public async Task<Response> EnrolMultipleItemsAsync(EnrolItemModel[] _items) {
    try {
        var result = await PostAsync<Response>("api/inventory/enrolmultipleitems", _items);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Message);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        App.Current.Logger.LogInfo("Exception at InventoryAPI - Error: EnrolItemAsync:");
        App.Current.Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
public Response EnrolMultipleItems(EnrolItemModel[] _items) {
    try {
        var result = Post<Response>("api/inventory/enrolmultipleitems", _items);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        App.Current.Logger.LogInfo("Exception at InventoryAPI - Error: EnrolItem:");
        App.Current.Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}

private async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string apiLocation, object postData) {
    var response = await client.PostAsync(apiLocation, postData.ToHttpContentString());
    T result = default(T);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        var json = await (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        result = DeserializeJson<T>(json);
    }
    return result;
}

private T Post<T>(string apiLocation, object postData) {
    var response = client.PostAsync(apiLocation, postData.ToHttpContentString()).Result;
    T result = default(T);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        result = DeserializeJson<T>(json);
    }
    return result;
}
public T DeserializeJson<T>(string json) {
    var parsed = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    return parsed;
}
}
```

I like this style of API and it has worked well in the Xamarin app, so now I wish to port this to Java - and here's where I'm stuck!

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class APIDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... ts) {
    String url = ts[0].toString();
    return Get(url);
}

private String Get(String url) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpEntity entity = null;
    String result = "";

    try {
        //Execute and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //final JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Catch no internet connectivity exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

And then a separate API class:

```
public class InventoryAPI {

public List<LocationModel> GetAllLocations() throws IOException {
    String url = "https://domain.com/api/inventory/getall";
    String response = null;// Get(url);

    try {
        response = new APIDownloader().execute(url).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    LocationModel[] mcArray = gson.fromJson(response, LocationModel[].class);
    return Arrays.asList(mcArray);
  }
}
```

Whilst the Java code above does work just fine (I've only implemented the GET so far) it does seem like it's going to get out of hand very quickly, especially after I port the POST methods in the C# library to the Java package.

What would be the best approach to replicate the Xamarin API Class I have above in Java?

Comment: "..it does seem like it's going to get out of hand very quickly..." Welcome to Java. ;) But in all seriousness, there are better ways to design an API than `AsyncTask`s, but your question is too vague to answer concisely and relies too heavily on opinion (i.e. use this design pattern or this library), imo.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to go native Java then do yourself a favor and use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). That will save you a ton of code in your API layer. Regular Java Http stuff is ugly, Retrofit makes it much easier.

When you get comfortable, look at [RxAndroid (RxJava)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) to really help with some of your Async code.